# Ordering a Drink in Non-Traditional Glassware

Tags: glassware, terminology, substitutions

I find drinks that are traditionally served in stemmed glasses are difficult to carry (I'm a wheelchair user). What terminology would I use if I wanted to order a drink like a martini or Manhattan served in a rocks glass (but without the ice)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the type of glass you are looking for is called an ["Old Fashioned glass"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Fashioned_glass) named for the cocktail typically served in it. Depending on the size of the drink you may possibly want request your drink in a "Double Old Fashioned glass". I would hope that simply requesting your martini be served in an Old Fashioned glass would suffice.

Comment: [Here is a list](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c1/ac/cb/c1accbd6c9e4768d38fd87a11dfb201c.jpg) to support @EricShain's suggestion.

Comment: Alternatively, ask for a [tumbler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumbler_(glass))which just refers to any glass in this category (including an old fashioned glass).